# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array ... for no conceivable reason

Tags: php, arrays, json

hello everyone I am writing a PHP rest API, and I have been having some truly baffling issues recently. I am trying to create an API that allows the user to upload user-generated content, the problem is that for some reason I get an `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` and I do not know why. the code for the script that I am working on is derivative for code that does work. this is the part of my sign up API that handles the input, no problems here:

```
$f = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonobj = stripslashes($f);
$obj = json_decode($jsonobj);

$email = $obj[0];
$password = $obj[1];
$country = $obj[2];
$city = $obj[3];
$broad = $obj[4];
$type = $obj[5];
$name = $obj[6];
```

but for some reason when I do the following, it refuses to work

```
$f = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonobj = stripslashes($f);
$obj = json_decode($jsonobj);

$serviceName = $obj[0];
$serviceType = $obj[1];
$serviceDescription = $obj[2];
$mon = $obj[3];
$tue = $obj[4];
$wed = $obj[5];
$thu = $obj[6];
$fri = $obj[7];
$sat = $obj[8];
$sun = $obj[9];
$hourStart = $obj[10];
$minStart = $obj[11];
$hourEnd = $obj[12];
$minEnd = $obj[13];
$price = $obj[14];
$currency = $obj[15];
$bizname = $obj[16];
```

the only difference from the first bit of code to the second one is that some of the objects in the array are numbers. I have tried `$obj = json_decode($jsonobj, true);` but I get a bunch of Undefined offsets

thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: @hanshenrik how is the first code snippet broken? I need the stripslashes for the android JSON library I am using

Comment: As mentioned by @brombeer please provide data samples you receive in ```file_get_contents('php://input');```

Comment: OkHttp: `{"currency":"us","fri":0,"hourEnd":1,"hourStart":1,"minEnd":36,"minStart":36,"mon":0,"name":"mybiz","price":"2","sat":0,"serviceDescription":"w","serviceName":"w","serviceType":"w","sun":0,"thu":0,"tue":0,"wed":0}`

Comment: @seigmüller You need to use key to access data like ```$obj["currency"], $obj["fri"]``` in this case as per your data. It will not work with index like 0,1... as data is associative array not index array

Comment: Your data will be look like ```Array
(
    [currency] => us
    [fri] => 0
    [hourEnd] => 1
    [hourStart] => 1
    [minEnd] => 36
    [minStart] => 36
    [mon] => 0
    [name] => mybiz
    [price] => 2
    [sat] => 0
    [serviceDescription] => w
    [serviceName] => w
    [serviceType] => w
    [sun] => 0
    [thu] => 0
    [tue] => 0
    [wed] => 0
)``` after using ```json_decode($jsonobj, true);```

Comment: If you don't use `json_decode($jsonobj, true);` JSON objects will be returned as objects. You could `print_r($obj);` to see its structure. Use `$obj->currency` then

Comment: so I copied the wrong thing the contents from `$f` were  D/OkHttp: `{"currency":"us","fri":0,"hourEnd":1,"hourStart":1,"minEnd":55,"minStart":55,"mon":0,"name":"my-biz","price":"2","sat":0,"serviceDescription":"w","serviceName":"w","serviceType":"w","sun":0,"thu":0,"tue":0,"wed":0}<br />`

Comment: @seigmüller fyi, you can [edit] your question and paste relevant data there. Thx